# Magento: exclude category from minimum order amount

Tags: php, xml, magento

Is it possible to exclude a category from the Magento minimum order amount?

A client needs a minimum order amount for every product (the minimum order is 50€) but he wants to exclude a specific category (since they are some bundles) from the minimum order amount. I've tried to add cart/catalog rules but I've resolved nothing.

Answer (score 0):

whitout extension a way is create a second store view,

this without the min amount rule and configurate a categorie inside this store view only whit the special products.

Comment: And how can I make that product available in the principal magento store?